# Can't get .htaccess to work

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, .htaccess, ubuntu-10.04

I'm using Apache2 on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx. I have config set to use `.htaccess` like normal. This is my default site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride all
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried lower case "all" (`AllowOverride all`) as well.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
//Rewrite all requests to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com/ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

//301 Redirect "old_junk.html" File to "new_junk.html"
Redirect 301 /old_junk.html /new_junk.html

//301 Redirect Entire Directory "old_junk/" to "new_junk/"
RedirectMatch 301 /old_junk/(.*) /new_junk//$1
```

(with `mydomain` replaced with my actual domain... and my computer is plugged in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct(add space between domain and '[NC]'):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: thanks. I updated that, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @orokusaki What doesn't work? mydomain.com -> www.mydomain.com? Do you enable rewrite(sudo a2enmod rewrite;service apache2 restart)?

Comment: ah, I didn't have it enabled, but I did, and restarted, and it still doesn't work :( Could it be something in a virtual host?

Comment: @orokusaki Yes, change "AllowOverride All"

Comment: I updated that (in my question also) and restarted, but still no dice :( Could it be something from another virtual-host? By the way, I'm putting the .htaccess in the web root of `mydomain.com`, not in some Apache config area.